# Crystal Reports - multiple rows to one row

Tags: crystal-reports

Fairly new to Crystal Reports...I have a table {deductions} that shows payroll deductions for employees. There are two deduction types per employee for this report.  Rather than show a line for each deduction record, I was hoping to have it display the amount for each code as a value on the same row. For example:

Smith, John Deduction1 $40.00
Smith, John Deduction2 $25.00
Doe, Jane Deduction1 $50.00
Doe, Jane Deduction2 $0.00

would be:

Smith, John $40.00 $25.00
Doe, Jane $50.00 $0.00

Is this possible in Crystal Reports?

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 formula fields in one filed place `Deduction 1` and in other place `Deduction 2`

Now create a group with name (if first name and last name are two saperate fields then first concatenate and then create group)

Now place the formula 1 and formula 2 in group header of footer as per your requriement